# MSSQL on Linux using second drive

Tags: sql-server, linux, performance, mount

I have an installation of Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) on Linux.  Developer edition of MSSQL, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE.

The SQL Server has used up all the space left in the boot partition on the main drive (about 150 GB).  I have a second drive about 700 GB that should do fine.

**Question:** For performance, am I best doing:

1)  Leaving SQL Server running on the boot partition on the original drive, and moving as many other things out of it.

2)  Mount /var/opt/mssql/data to a different partition, same drive.

3)  Mount /var/opt/mssql/data to the second drive.

4)  Tell SQL Server to place files on the second drive directly without mount (not sure how that would be done)

5)  Somethin' else

Also, if I have a swap file partition that's getting hit when SQL Server gets memory hungry, would it be better to have that on the secondary drive for some reason?

thanks

Comment: You'll probably be better off getting an answer on http://dba.stackexchange.com rather than here. As for performance, however, we don't have enough detail to answer that. Say, for example, that the existing Drive that SQL Server is on is an SSD, but your other drive is a HDD, then performance will be better where it is. Is your question really about performance, or are you simply asking how to move the installation location of SQL Server on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: No not really about moving installation location, but what way to utilize a second free drive to get the most performance.  For the sake of argument, assume the drives are the same.

Comment: Still depends; but (generally) the service will perform better if it has its data files on a separate physical disk.